# How to chroot a job within sun grid engine?

Tags: linux, chroot, sungridengine

I have a two part question about making our cluster more secure from accidental changes and deletions from running cluster jobs. I don't care about restricting the read or execute permissions of the job, basically I want the job to not be able to delete or change any files outside of its initial directory.

1) Is it possible to chroot a job submitted to sun grid so the job can only write to directory specified when the job is submitted?

2) It is possible to do the above but also allow read-only access to the rest of the system with all paths intact? essentially to have the filesystem appear normal and complete, but the job can only write and delete from the directory it started in.

Comment: From my quick searches, chroot typically requires root privileges, so this is going to be tough to do as regular user submitting job. Maybe the use of `prolog` configuration option may work? See http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_conf.html

Comment: Also, according to this old post (circa 2008), seems like a workaround is needed to get this done: http://arc.liv.ac.uk/pipermail/gridengine-users/2008-June/019097.html